# My US visa has been stamped over by the immigration officer. Would this cause any issues?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration

When I entered the US last time , the officer at the port of the entry put the stamp partially on the visa page .Then he turned the page and stamped it there as well. Now I am worried about the stamp markings on the visa page. I have traveled multiple times to the US and this has never happened before.Will it really be an issue when I travel to the states again

[image]

Does this stamp on the visa page mean anything?

Comment: This is typical if your visa is single entry, this means the visa has been used. If yours is multiple entry, then it is meaningless unless he wrote something (like CWOP) on it.

Comment: I am on H1 visa and its a multiple entry.He wrote nothing on it .My wishful thinking is that it was a mistake and not intentional ..

Comment: Can't think of any other meanings.